# My wireless router stops working temporarily whenever opening a folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-router, connection

Whenever I open my Downloads folder (the one that came with the default install, where my browser and torrent downloads go) on my Windows 7 PC, my Internet connect dies for a few minutes. I'm usually on my MacBook as well, and I notice on here that it is in fact the wireless network that goes out (it disappears from AirPort), not just the Internet connection.

I only recently deduced that the folder was the source of the problem. I tried turning off network sharing for the folder, but it made no difference. I have no idea how this is even possible. Does anyone have any ideas?

The folder currently houses probably upwards of 100 GB of movie files, and maybe a few miscellaneous other stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might consider editing your post to include the model of your router and firmware revision.

Answer (score 0):

strange problem.. but here's my suggestions anyway:

1. try to remove some files from the folder.. move it to download2/ perhaps :P
2. did the router restart itself?

Comment: The router isn't restarting itself right now. I haven't really figured out fully how this works, but for sure, when I come home and open my downloads folder, the router goes down. It doesn't go down everytime I oepn it, but it will happen several times a day.

Answer (score 0):

Some wireless routers made in 2002 would have this problem. Sadly, some made yesterday still do. All you can do about it is: Update your router firmware to the absolute latest, then start looking for beta and third-party firmwares. If dd-wrt is compatible, you're gold, that thing is rock solid once you get it to work. Update your wireless to the latest driver for your wireless from the vendor, but if you have then also consider removing it and getting the generic Windows Update version.

I remember when Linksys refused to acknowledge a similar hard hang problem in the WRT54G for many years, then one day there was a firmware update and it never hung again. Complaining to the company enough will eventually get it fixed.

Oh, and check out its physical location. Is it near a source of heat, does it feel hot? Maybe it's just overheating.